# Default tab for completed elections should be "election", not "nomination"

Tags: feature-request, election, election-page

The election pages have three tabs for the three stages of the election:

- nomination
- primary
- election

During each of the stages, the election page will default to tab for that stage.  E.g., during the "primary" stage, the election page defaults to the "primary" tab.

For completed elections, however, the page defaults to the first "nomination" stage.  I'm not sure exactly when this happens, but I suspect it happens when results are posted.

For completed elections, it would seem to make more sense to default to the "election" tab because this tab:

- shows you how you voted (if you voted), and
- explains how the votes are counted (in the right side bar).

Answer (score 2):

The nomination page contains more information -- all the candidates rather than just the 10 that advanced to the election stage, and all the comments.  Here's an [example](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/1) from an election with 19 candidates.

Yes, this means you have to click the "election" phase to see how you voted.  But all other visitors -- people who didn't participate in that election -- see all the information without even having to know to go click another tab.  I think it's ok to place the extra burden on the people who, demonstrably, know how to navigate election pages.

Comment: People can see all information regardless of which tab is the default tab.  Could you please explain why the nomination tab is a more valuable default to anyone (voters or nonvoters) once the election is complete and results are published?  In my view, information about candidates who didn't make it past the nomination phase is of low importance and of higher importance is who you voted for, how the votes were counted, and who was running in the election.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill I explained that. Most people who visit that page, IMO (you don't seem to have data either) *didn't* vote, so "see your votes" isn't relevant. When I look at a past election page, either I voted and probably know who I voted for (might not remember the order, but meh) or I *didn't* vote but I want to see how the election went. One use case for that is that another election is happening, so you want to see who stood last time and what they said and what seemed to be important to commenters. You haven't made a case for "see my votes" being more important than seeing full history.